# SharePoint list filtering condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view

I'm trying to filter a list on a number of conditions where if a column does not equal a value then dont show in the view.

If Programme = 'bbc1' Dont show in list

If Programme = 'bbc2' Dont show in list

etc.

However I cannot seem to get this logic to work. Is it possible?
I haven’t Indexed the 'Programme' column, does it need to be?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems counterintuitive, but the filter worked for me when I changed the Or to and And.

[image: All Items view]

[image: Test view]

[image: Test view filter]

Comment: I thought I tried that, Its working :)